# How to save image in local file system with cordova.file in windows phone 8?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, web-applications, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

In a cordova project, I'm saving the images in a local directory, its working fine for Android.

```
guardarFoto: function (file) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file, sql.resolveOnSuccess, sql.onError);
},

resolveOnSuccess: function (entry) {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();

    var newfilename = n + ".jpg";
    var myfolderapp = "MemoFoto";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function (filesys) {
            filesys.root.getDirectory(myfolderapp, { create: true, exclusive: false },
                function (directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newfilename, sql.escribirComentario, sql.onError);
                }, sql.onError);
        }, sql.onError);
},

 //part of an object: var sql = {};
```

The same functions in Android make its own directory in the root, but in wp8 it just saves it in the camera roll. why is this?

But is not working for wp8, its said to be supported in the docs http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html